# What is the correct way to create a modular site from asciidoc files?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have lot of documentation written in AsciiDoc and correctly separated into folders. I use asciidoctor with a custom CSS to render my docs to HTML. The problem with this is that it generates a *single* HTML page that is **very** long. I was surfing the web and found that the atom docs are also written in AsciiDoc, but these docs have not all the information together, in fact they are separated into different sections.

Here the atom docs: https://atom.io/docs/v0.201.0/getting-started-why-atom

I want to know if there is a tool that can generate this, a flag or a specific syntax.

I think it is not really user friendly to have all the info in one long single page.

Answer (score 0):

I have a site where the static content is generated using the [asciidoctor-jekyll](https://github.com/asciidoctor/jekyll-asciidoc) plugin and [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/).

I had also plugged the [java](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctorj) version of asciidoctor to generate views with the play framework at some point but decided that I prefer that the content I generate with asciidoctor to be static and delivered by a CDN.

EDIT:

Also, [GitBookIO](http://help.gitbook.com/format/asciidoc.html) supports asciidoctor.